# Clear chrome tab history with JS code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have created some shortcuts in my application. If I open chrome and go directly to my website, without opening other tabs first, the shortcut works as expected (The key is: ctrl+shift+T). If I open other tabs first, and then go to my site, the tab history is filled with the previous tabs I have accessed. Therefore my shortcut doesn't work, and instead of opening the dropdown, it opens the tabs from the history.

Searching a solution for this, peoples advice is "Close chrome and reopen it, then the tab history is gone". But this is not a solution for me. Is there a way I can go around this? I have tried adding to my code: `e.preventDefault();`

But this does not work. My entire code is seen below.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {

var pressedKey = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toUpperCase();
array = isoNS.getArr(); //Array containing IDs and shortcuts

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

var objectKey = array[i].objectKey.toUpperCase();

if(e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey) {       
    e.preventDefault();

    if(pressedKey == objectKey) {
    isoNS.injectKey(array[i].objectContainerId);
    }       
}
}
```

}

So I guess that what I want to do when the user presses ctrl+shift+T, is to clear the tab history, and then apply the ctrl+shift+T on my site.

Ps. This is only an issue in chrome, and not other browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interesting discussion about this [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-bugs/Ntc1byZXHfU). Essentially;

> certain control key combinations have been reserved for browser 
>   usage only and can no longer be intercepted by the client side JavaScript 
>   in the web page.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> unfortunately is one of these combinations, so you will not be able to capture it with JavaScript.